# Can someone identify and fix my compatibility issue Photoshop CS5 and Mojave

Tags: mac, crash, adobe-photoshop, macos-mojave, photoshop-cs5

as with many others I have tried to install my copy of CS5 with apples Mojave and have come into difficulty.

I recently purchased a 2017 MacBook Pro (secondhand) due to my 2012 MacBook Pro mysteriously dying a death (can't find a solution to fix it, so its essentially an expensive paperweight), and to my horror I discovered that I may not be able to use my version of photoshop with the current version of the operating system.

After a fair bit of time with the tech support people on Adobe and reading the many different forums, seeing the issues others have encountered, I'm down to a small issue and hopefully someone of you out there can help resolve it for me:

I have installed photoshop CS5 on my MacBook, it opens and is fully functional - to a point. I can adjust images, add in the IPTC data etc, but when I click "ok" to save the IPTC data, photoshop crashes, I believe its a segmentation fault - which means there's some issue with the coding -at a guess missing old out of date drivers, so I'm close to having it operational, I just can't seem to find out what needs to be adjusted to fix it.

Also, Adobe Updater keeps telling me that some updates can't be installed - I have installed some of them manually via terminal but it hasn't resolved my problem.

Below is a crash report that I receive after I click "ok" after adding text(IPTC data) to a file.

```
Process:               Adobe Photoshop CS5 [356]
Path:                  /Applications/Adobe Photoshop CS5/Adobe Photoshop CS5.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Photoshop CS5
Identifier:            com.adobe.Photoshop
Version:               12.0.5 [12.0.520120529.r.1321] (12.0.5x20120529.r.1321] [12.0.5)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Adobe Photoshop CS5 [356]
User ID:               501


Date/Time:             2019-07-12 06:50:50.650 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.5 (18F132)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        F2404F12-E269-A3D1-D8A9-436A7E4432F7




Time Awake Since Boot: 39 seconds


System Integrity Protection: enabled


Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread


Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00003eaddd4dec20
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY


Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [356]


VM Regions Near 0x3eaddd4dec20:
    Memory Tag 240         0000000124057000-0000000124e17000 [ 13.8M] ---/rwx SM=NUL 
-->
    MALLOC_NANO            0000600000000000-0000600008000000 [128.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV
```

Many thanks in advance for any assistance in understanding the problem or getting a work around, the character count per post limits how much of the crash log I could post.

Comment: I have tried to copy and paste the full crash report but the system says it looks like spam (also the character count limit)

Comment: I am running photoshop CS5 on a 2013 iMac with Mojave. Photoshop crashes when you exit the application. Other than that, everything else works fine. Where did you get the CS5 installation files and the updates? I assume you did not use a installation DVD. If you are willing to install Sierra, then I believe you will not have any problems with crashes.

Answer (score 1):

From MacWorld - [How to open apps that won’t work in Mojave - including Photoshop](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/open-apps-mojave-photoshop-3684425/)

> **How to fix Photoshop crashes in Mojave**
>
> 1. Open System Preferences
> 2. Go to Security & Privacy
> 3. Open the Accessibility tab
> 4. Click the lock and enter your password
> 5. Look for Adobe Photoshop CS5 and the message “Allow the apps below to control your computer”.

Comment: Thanks for the input, afraid that it doesn't work - that's primarily for people who cannot install photoshop, I have it installed ...just can't get it to adjust images.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have anything else, & I haven't seen CS5 since about 2012 when CS6 was released. Adobe stopped development & support of CS5 at that time, so updating your OS is always going to have this potential consequence.